# Facing issue in Flutter app related to LazyPut

Tags: flutter

I hope you will send me a good solution for this problem.

```
class TabsBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() async {
    Get.lazyPut(() => TabsController(parser: Get.find()));
    Get.lazyPut(() => AppointmentController(parser: Get.find()));
    Get.lazyPut(() => HistoryController(parser: Get.find()));
    Get.lazyPut(() => AnalyticsController(parser: Get.find()));
    Get.lazyPut(() => CalendarsController(parser: Get.find()));
    Get.lazyPut(() => ProfileController(parser: Get.find()));
  }
}
```

When we call this page, it gives this error

```
TabsParser not found, You need to call Get.put(TabsParser()) or Get.lazyPut(()=\>TabsParser())
```

I tried this code

```
Get.lazyPut(() => TabsController(
  parser: Get.put(
    TabsParser( 
      sharedPreferencesManager: SharedPreferencesManager(sharedPreferences: null),     
      apiService: ApiService(appBaseUrl: "http://api.xxxxx.xxx/")
    )
  )
);
```

which works but doesn't pass id's so the code doesn't work.